# MacOS - when typing quotes on keyboard it is highlighting and double press needed

Tags: macos, layout, keyboard

I'have upgraded to MacOS High Sierra and now have a problem. When I press ' or " button quote underlines and I need to type it again or press "space" to remove underline and continue typing. Also, if I enter letters a,o,e,i after pressing ' - it changes quote to á,ó,é,í. This is not smart quotes and I can't find any settings to turn this off.
Keyboard layout is set to USA international (PC).
How can I return normal quotes input?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Set it from English US International - PC to Englisch US.

Comment: Thanks, this also solved an issue with the tilde symbol.

Comment: Do you know why does the International do that?

Comment: It's just one way to enter so called Diacritic Marks. Today, if you don't have the desired Keyboard, you can just press and hold e,a,o, etc. to to enter special characters like é, è, à or ó. Before this, entering these chars without the right keyboard was more complicated. You had to enter Alt+<some code> to get the right character. So they came up with this layout where you could get ñ by hitting ~ and n for example. I believe nowadays this layout is not used very often anymore.

Comment: Took a long time to figure it out. tks a lot

Comment: you'e a legend man